# How to reclaim a hijacked tinyurl?

Tags: redirects

It seems someone has hijacked one of the TinyURLs that was sent out in the marketing communication and it now redirects users to a porn site. Is there anyway we can reclaim the TinyURL?

Comment: Are you sure the tinyurl was hijacked and not your web page?

Comment: Absolutely as it redirects the user to a page hosted at Blogger.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - Why do you think TinyURL was hijacked and that it's not a typo in the marketing communication?

Comment: @Ciaran - I cannot for certain confirm that there was a typo but it has been acknowledged that the link had been verified prior to publication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@PeanutsMonkey You didn't really answer John's question. At least it doesn't seem so. You just restated that people end up at a porn site. (Maybe you're just being brief at the cost of clarity.) I'm not sure it's even possible to "take over" an existing TinyURL in the way you're describing.

Use [LongURL](http://longurl.org/) to find out where the tinyurl is really pointing. It'll also show you if there are subsequent redirects. So if you first see your original URL, and then the porn site, that means the redirect is happening on your end, not via TinyURL itself.

For example I just created [this tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com/3du9gh) by shortening `http://apple.com/store` which Apple redirects to their preferred location of `http://store.apple.com/us` and here are the [LongURL results](http://longurl.org/expand?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftinyurl.com%2F3du9gh) showing that there's even an intermediate redirect they put you through.

Comment: @Su'- Thanks for suggesting LongURL. It is a fantastic tool to be using. I pasted in the TinyURL and there is only a single redirect i.e. it goes to the porn side immediately not via our website. Also I didn't quite follow what you meant by `encoding http://apple.com/store`.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey For me it sounds like typo then -- possibly you were using the wrong tiny URL -- wrong letter case of single letter ... or 1 extra random character  ... or 1 character short. I see no other ways how it can be hijacked otherwise.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I just meant that was the original URL shortened. Edited to clarify. I'm also leaning toward this being a typo. The URL must have been e-mailed around or something to whoever composed the text for the marketing. Have you checked archives to make sure?

Comment: @LazyOne - Thanks. It is indeed a possibility that it could have been a typo and no one will know unless we trawl through all email communications.

Comment: @Su' - Thanks. We are thinking of investigating the archives to identify the miscommunication if any.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Try shortening the same URL again and compare result to that problematic TinyURL. I have not used TinyURL myself, but I think it should generate the same ID if such target URL is already present in their DB.